# My javafx, doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jvm, crash-reports

I have a problem with a JavaFX, if I run my code, the JVM throws the following error:

```
#

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=9524, tid=0x0000000000001ac0

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x0000000000000000

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\Krzysztof\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\YouTubeFX\hs_err_pid9524.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What video card do you have? Could you try upgrading your video drivers, or (if already on the latest version) revert to an earlier release?

Comment: Additionally, you could try JDK 1.8.0_131 or a [JDK 9 build](http://jdk.java.net/9/).  What was in the error report file?

Comment: Complete crash logs are required to investigate more. Problematic frame suggest there is native crash ( C  0x0000000000000000 ). You could share C:\Users\Krzysztof\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\YouTubeFX\hs_err_pid9524.log for more accurate results

Comment: http://wklej.to/KF9kX here is file hs_err_pid9524.log